# How to store string arrays inside a for & for-each iteration

Tags: java, arrays, string

Here are  `for loop`and `for (Element link : links)`loopings .
     I want to store every elements `title` to `line[]`

What should I do ?

```
   String[] line = new String[100];

     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfResultpages; i++) {

             ......

                for (Element link : links) {

                    String title = link.text();
                    String url = link.absUrl("href"); 
                    url = URLDecoder.decode(url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1, url.indexOf('&')), "UTF-8");

                    if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
                        continue; // 
                    }
                    System.out.println("Title: " + title);


                    line[ numberOfResultpages ]=title;  //I don't know how to store every title element into line here 
               // }

        }
             }
```

## Update

`numberOfResultpages` is not  the maximum size of the array
a `numberOfResultpages` can have many element`title`

Comment: is this --> `numberOfResultpages` the maximum size of the array?

Comment: @Ousmane Mahy Diaw No , a `numberOfResultpages` can have many element` title`

Comment: take ArrayLst instead of Strng array

Comment: @evalwt, have a look at the updated code. You need to assign sufficient memory first if you are using `int[]`.

Comment: @Devendra Lattu int[] ?

Comment: @Shiva Nandam Could you make a solution ?

Comment: @evalwt, sorry I meant to say `String[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] line = new String[numberOfResultpages * links.size()]; // assign adequate size to line array.

int idx = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfResultpages; i++) {

    ...
    for (Element link : links) {
       ...
       line[idx++]=title;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try By using ArrayList**:

```
List<Strng> list=new ArrayLst<String>();
 for (int i = 0; i < numberOfResultpages; i++) {
   .........
//Every thing same
//add like this, ArrayList is Dynamic in Size
list.add(title);
} }
```